# Java not recognizing public classes in same project file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm coding in Java using IntelliJ IDEA 2022 on Windows 10. I run each program from IntelliJ's terminal using the following command:

`cmd /c --% java -cp <Location of .jar file of library I use> FileName.java`

This worked fine for running programs that only contained methods from that library. However, now that I want to use methods from another class I wrote that is in the same folder as the one I want to run, it throws the following error:

`error: cannot find symbol`

How can I solve this?
I'm quite new to programming so sorry if the question is a bit unclear

Comment: https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java/java-project-overview-compilation-and-execution.html my best guess is you are not compiling the other classes

Comment: the `Filename.java` is wrong for sure. Java Runtime only works with `.class` files, but you never have to specify that extension there.

Comment: Oh and please note that with IDEA you could start the program with the little green play icon inside the editor window (next to the `main` method or the class that contains the `main` method). Just make sure that in the "Project Structure" dialog you add the required libs - first to the available "Libraries", then as dependency to the "Modules" where you need them.

Comment: @cyberbrain I know, but it somehow is the only thing that works. Writing that command seems to both compile and run the script. First compiling it using javac works, but whenI try to run it with the java command and no .java at the end it just says it doesn't find the class.

Comment: you have to prefix the classname with the packagename - if you use that.

Comment: @cyberbrain: since Java 11 the `java` command accepts a _single_ sourcefile and compiles _and_ runs it, using (only) classes available in the classpath, exactly as OP describes. See the doc or the help/usage message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do more coding in Java, I would recommend that you don't work with manual compilation and execution, but use a build system like [Gradle](https://gradle.org) or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org)

Both follow the "Convention over Configuration" approach, Maven more than Gradle, that means you have to place your code into a specific folder structure. But you also have to create a small configuration file (either `build.gradle` for Gradle or `pom.xml` for Maven).

As you use IntelliJ IDEA, you could simply create a project as Gradle or Maven project inside the IDE, which creates the folder structure for you, but I would also recommend that you work through the respective "Getting started" sections of the documentation.

While using a build system gives you the burden of learning an additional system from the beginning, it will make your life as developer so much easier on the long run, that I would say it is worth to learn that stuff early.

Plan B: When you do not want to learn it (or not yet), you could use a track of Oracles Java Tutorial to learn how to first compile and then run Java code in two individual steps. The chapter is called ["Hello World!" for Microsoft Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html). While the tutorial was written for an older version of Java (JDK 8) and does not cover the trick with the compiling and running a single Java class with one command, it still is a good source for some more basic steps. Compiling and running java classes in a way that multiple classes can be used together is one of them.